# Как обрабатывать изображения в Webpack 5?

Tags: javascript, изображения, webpack, assets

Начал изучать Webpack и пока имеется такая конфигурация:

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    context: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
    mode: 'development',
    entry: {
        main: './index.js'
    },
    output: {
        filename: '[name].[hash].js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        clean: true
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: "./index.html"
        })
    ],
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.css$/i,
                use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader']
            },
            {
                test: /\.(jpg|png|svg|jpeg|gif)$/,
                type: 'asset/resource'
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

Проблема заключается в том что когда в html файле я вставляю картинку `<img src="./assets/img/logo.png">` то после сборки картинка не как не обрабатывается и в конечной директории даже не появляется. Хотя если работать с картинкой в js файле `import logo from './assets/img/logo.png'` то всё прекрасно работает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Спасибо за ответ, да copy-webpack-plugin решает эту проблему, но я нашел и другое решение: установка лоадера html-loader. Его можно просто подключить и всё будет работать как надо без всяких дополнительных настроек.

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    context: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
    mode: 'development',
    entry: {
        main: './index.js'
    },
    output: {
        filename: '[name].[hash].js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        clean: true
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: "./index.html"
        })
    ],
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.html$/,
                use: 'html-loader'
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader']
            },
            {
                test: /\.(jpg|png|svg|jpeg|gif)$/,
                type: 'asset/resource'
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Поставьте пакет

```
   npm i -D copy-webpack-plugin
```

2. В файле конфигурации  `webpack.config.js`

```
const CopyPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  plugins: [ new CopyPlugin({
    patterns: [
        {
          from: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/images'),
          to:   path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist/images')
        }
      ]
    })
  ]
}
```

Подправьте паттерны и пути под свои задачи. Например, отдельная папка с svg, вторая с картинками, отдельно файл иконки и т.д.

Плагин просто тупо копирует все файлы, какие есть в папках, не размышляя, будут они нужны или нет.

Comment: В Webpack 5 этот плагин уже не нужен

Comment: Andreymal, а что там теперь вместо него? Кстати, на офф. сайте https://webpack.js.org/plugins/copy-webpack-plugin/ о том, что он устарел (или устареет) не написано, так что вариант рабочий.

Comment: Вместо него теперь ассеты, как у автора в вопросе написано